# Make emacs format Java more consistently

Tags: indentation, formatting, java, tabs

When I open Java files originally created and edited in Emacs, the indentation shows up correctly, as in the image below:

[image: Java file made in emacs]

However, when I open the same file in Sublime Text, or any other editor besides Emacs, the indentation is messed up, and I can see that it's because Emacs inconsistently mixes spaces and tabs:

[image: The same file opened in sublime text]

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: That's happening because your Emacs is using a tab width of 8, while sublime is using a tab width of 4. That's easy to fix, but if it's an option at all I would just follow Drew's answer and stop using tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set option **`indent-tabs-mode`** to `nil`:

Put this in your init file, to make Emacs always indent using `SPC` characters, never `TAB` characters.

```el
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Comment: Also for reference: the manual page on [tabs vs spaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Just-Spaces.html), which discusses precisely this issue.